# I wanted to write a code where you can calculate the distance and slope of a line/ i keep on getting an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def main():

    first_x = (input(" What is your first X value? :  "))
    second_x = (input("What is your second X value? : "))
    first_y = (input("What is your first Y value? : "))
    second_y = (input("What is your second Y vlaue? : "))

    print(str(first_x) + "," + str(first_y))
    print(str(second_x) + "," + str(second_y))

    top_slope = ("second_y - first_y")
    bottom_slope =("second_x - first_x")

    print("Your top slope is") + "top_slope"
    print("Your Bottom slope is") + "bottom_slope"

    user_choice = input("Do you want the slope or the distance? ")
    if user_choice == ("slope"):
        if ("second_x - first_x") == 0:
            print("The slope is undefined. ")
        elif ("second_y - first_y") == 0:
            print("The slope is zero. ")
        else:
            slope = ("top_slope / bottom_slope")
            print(slope)
    elif user_choice == ("distance"):
        distance = ((second_x - first_x)**2 + (second_y - first_y)**2)**.5
        print("distance")
    else:
            print_1 = ("This wasnt slope or distance")
            print("print_1")
Main():
```

When I tell python to run the program python keeps on giving me an error on the last line (`Main():`) and when I solve that error other errors keep on popping up everywhere.

Comment: The last line is `Main()` not `Main():`. And numeric variables (`int`, `float`) do NOT go between quotation marks.

Comment: ...Why is so much of your code enclosed in quotes? `"second_y - first_y"` is just a string, it doesn't do any math.

Comment: I think you meant `str()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code cleaned up so it runs:

```
def main():

    first_x = int(input(" What is your first X value? :  "))
    second_x = int(input("What is your second X value? : "))
    first_y = int(input("What is your first Y value? : "))
    second_y = int(input("What is your second Y vlaue? : "))

    print("First", str(first_x) + "," + str(first_y))
    print("Second", str(second_x) + "," + str(second_y))

    top_slope = second_y - first_y
    bottom_slope = second_x - first_x

    print("Your top slope is", top_slope)
    print("Your Bottom slope is", bottom_slope)

    user_choice = input("Do you want the slope or the distance?")
    if user_choice == "slope":
        if (second_x - first_x) == 0:
            print("The slope is undefined. ")
        elif (second_y - first_y) == 0:
            print("The slope is zero. ")
        else:
            slope = top_slope / bottom_slope
            print("slope is", slope)
    elif user_choice == "distance":
        distance = ((second_x - first_x)**2 + (second_y - first_y)**2)**.5
        print("distance", distance)
    else:
        print("This wasnt slope or distance")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is case sensitive.  Therefore `Main():` is **not** the same as `main():`.  Furthermore, when **declaring** functions the syntax `def somefunc(args):` ending with the colon is used.  When **calling** a function, you forego the colon and just type `somefunc()`.  Finally, you don't need a main function.  Python is not C and will start interpreting whatever commands you give it right from the beginning of the file.